# Change gradle's temp directory when used with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, jvm-arguments, temp, tmp

Using Gradle 2.10 within Android Studio, I'm having some problems with the amount of space on my root partition combined with the fact that gradle produces quite a lot of tmp files.
I'd like to change my gradle tmp file to ~/tmp, but so far haven't managed to do so.

Things I've tried:

```
$ export TEMP=TMP=TMPDIR=<home folder>/tmp
$ studio &
```

No success, gradle still uses `/tmp`.

Modify java.io.tmpdir via Gradle's jvmargs in gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -Djava.io.tmpdir=<home folder>/tmp
```

Still no success.

Of course, my root issue is the lack of space on `/`, and I have managed to get it usable for some time more, but unless I completely reconfigured lots of stuff on my machine I will run short from time to time. Since my home directory is mounted on a 1 TB partition it would be nice to use it for tmp files instead.

Actually, if there's a solution system-wide that also affects gradle, that would be just as good or even better. Any ideas?

---

UPDATE: This does not seem to actually be about / being full, even though "No space left on device" is what's reported. After making sure my / partition has lots of space this still happened.

After searching some more I found http://www.out4mind.com/en/android-studio-updates-error-linux/ which suggests setting the tmpdir from studio64.vmoptions:

```
$ echo "-Djava.io.tmpdir=<<<home folder>>>/tmp" >> ~/.AndroidStudio<<<version>>>/studio64.vmoptions
```

I tried that, but after restarting AS, the same error persists. I also verified using

jps -lvm

that my java.io.tmpdir is in fact set. Still no success though.

I'm starting to think that this might be NDK related because my project has native code and I do use the gradle-experimental plugin with NDK support. Question is which device is full, is there a RAM disk involved when invoking the native compiler?

Comment: What Gradle version is used in your Android Studio?

Comment: Gradle version is 2.10.

Comment: Hmm I'm starting to think that something else is causing this. Before I cleaned up my / partition it was 92% full. Even though that's not really near 100%, I didn't think more about it. But now I cleaned it down to 81% (3.5GB free) and gradle still throws IOException("No space left on device") as soon as I try to build. Maybe worth noting is that I use the gradle-experimental android studio plugin together with the NDK because my project includes native code.

Comment: Is there another volume such as a RAM disk involved with NDK gradle builds? Because I can't see how a volume with 3.5 GB could even be the one that's depleted.

Comment: Oops https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206150

Comment: Turns out my disk had plenty of space, but was out of inodes. Ended up re-installing my ubuntu box. Still not able to override the tmp directory though (works when invoking gradle from console, not from AS), but the problem is no longer relevant for me.